# Как синхронизировать дату с телефона на проект в Unity?(версия Unity:2023.1.11f1)

Tags: unity3d

(версия Unity:2023.1.11f1)
Вкратце о проекте: приложение должно показывать сколько осталось дней до нового года,
эта информация должна выводиться на белый плакат(указан стрелкой).
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я не знаю как узнать текущую дату и месяц(если можете- объясните как дата и месяц будут записываться в коде.) Я думал сделать так-пример:
записать- январь=0, февраль=31, Март=59 и т.д.
потом выводить в переменную месяц например-май(май=120)+нынешняя дата-(например:17) и получается мы складываем 120+17=137 и вычитаем это из всех дней в году(365) и в итоге получаем сколько дней осталось до нового года )

Comment: [DateTime и TimeSpan](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.datetime?view=net-8.0#datetime-vs-timespan)

Comment: я не очень понял, можешь объяснить?